# FB.init is causing Facebook tab setAutoGrow() to not work

Tags: facebook

I have the following code near the end of my HTML document, right before the `</body>` tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
    FB.init({ 
        appId : 'My app id', 
        status : true, 
        cookie : true, 
        xfbml : true 
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
</script>
```

It does not work. However, when I get rid of the FB.init function, auto-resizing works:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
</script>
```

Is there a way of having a page have a window.fbAsyncInit and provide the appId to the Facebook API at the same time?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue, i am having the same problem.  Manually setting height in the Canvas settings at the moment to be very long.

Comment: I can assure you, that without `init`, `setAutoGrow` is not going to do anything, so you must be doing something else which is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about window.fbAsyncInit, it is used when the javascript is loaded asyncronously, as below. So removing this wrapper function should solve your issue.

```
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; } js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"; d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
} (document));
```